# Does std::basic_string formally have an implicitly generated move constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics

I'm aware that `std::basic_string` in practice supports move semantics, but the rvalue reference argument constructor I find in C++11 looks like this in the class definition:

*C++11 §21.4/5*:

> ```
> basic_string(basic_string&&, const Allocator&);
> ```

Then in the detailed discussion it's again shown without a default for the allocator argument:

*C++11 §21.4.2/17*:

> ```
> basic_string(basic_string&& str, const Allocator& alloc);
> ```

Disregarding obvious intent that the class should be movable, does the class then formally have an implicitly generated move constructor?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Copied and pasted from the final draft N3290. The draft following after the voting isn't the standard really (since it wasn't what was voted on), but it may have editorial fix-up for that? For the last declaration I'm on page 645, if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment. I didn't notice that the one you found also exists (further down the class definition, over a page break), as well as the move constructor.

Comment: Oh, they're at top. I'm blind. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not implicit, but explicit. Also in C++11 21.4/5 is

```
basic_string(basic_string&& str) noexcept;
```